# Spark History - Log timestamps have wrong time zone

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jvm, apache-spark-sql

When I submit a job on a set of machines machine located in London timezone, the Spark Master on the dashboard has the correct time, but the dashboard of history server shows time that is 1 hrs ahead which is GMT. Is there a way to fix this in Apache Spark?

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely that your log timestamps don't have "wrong" time zone, but either your spark cluster was located in GMT, or the conf was set as:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "GMT")
```

Change this line explicitly to London timezone (BST?)

Or use the fancy from_utc_timestamp function which lets you specify a timezone while converting ts

Also check whether your ts is in milliseconds, and set -Duser.timezone in JVM config spark.executor.extraJavaOptions

Comment: From where can i change the setting?

Comment: application code. some setups allow editing a spark properties config file